# Modeling irregularly shaped flower bed

Tags: mesh, texturing, bezier-curves, geometry

I'm looking to model this flower bed which is a slightly atypical shape. I would quite like it to be as realistic as possible but only have a 4gb nvidia card so realise i might have to balance.

[image]

I'm thinking

1. Draw a bezier curve for the wall shape and convert to mesh.
2. Extrude in Z and use solidify modifier to get basic shape.
3. For wall texture, i guess find a image texture/roughness map etc and use that.
4. For plants I have a Botaniq add-on which generates nice plants
5. Soil - i'm not sure, probably easier to use an image texture i guess as opposed to a particle system? or maybe a procedural texture might work for soil?

Any thoughts about how to proceed with any steps would be gratefully received.

THanks

Comment: I think you're on a good way. I can only advise against using a particle system for the soil. As long as you're not going for little clumps of soil trickling around or whatever, this would be overkill. An image texture maybe with a bump map or displacement if you need more unevenness would be better.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.